# How to fix strange behavior of Auth::loginUsingId() when I set remember me argument to true in laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

in `AuthController`, in order to login the user by id, I tried `Auth::loginUsingId($id, $remember)` with both true and false values for $remember. in both cases, login is successful, but the problem is when I set `$remember = true`, it will redirect back and the codes after that will be ignored:

set to `false`

```
Auth::loginUsingId($id, false);
dd('test'); // this line or anything else will execute after logging the user in
```

set to `true`

```
Auth::loginUsingId($id, true);
dd('test'); // this line or anything else will ignored and redirect back immediately
// after loggin the user in
```

I totally confused why this happens. I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are sure that the login system works fine and the only problem is with remember me option, it could be because of missing `remember_me` column or some changes that you've made on `remember_me` column that you shouldn't do in your users migration.

make sure you have the following line in your users migration, if you are using version 8 of laravel as you have used it's tag:

```
$table->rememberToken();
```

and if you are using older version of laravel, you should have the following line:

```
$table->string('remember_me', 100)->nullable();
```

Comment: I am really grateful, your answer directly pointed to my problem.
I have used users migration from my previous project and in that project, I've removed the remember_me line, so I added this line as you mentioned and now it works fine :))

Comment: @junior_developer_70  It usually happens, I'm glad that it works now.